# Spark job scheduler without YARN/MESOS

Tags: apache-spark, scheduler, oozie, datastax-enterprise

I want to schedule some spark jobs in specified time intervals. Every scheduler that I found works only with Yarn/Mesos(e.g. Oozie, Luigi, Azkaban, Airflow).  I'm running Datastax and it doesn't have the option of running with Yarn or Mesos. I saw somewhere that maybe Oozie can work with Datastax but couldn't find any help for that. Is there any solution to this problem or the only one is to write a scheduler myself?

Comment: The good old Linux CRONTAB can run something at *"specified time intervals"*, e.g. `5/15 * * * * myjob` will run "myjob" every 15 minutes, 24/7, starting at 0:05. By the way, Oozie now supports CRONTAB syntax because, well, it's tried and true...